# Change UITableView delete button text after it's first shown (in editing mode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to change the delete text displayed by a UITableView once editing mode has begun.

The delegate method:

```
 -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called only when the deleteButton at index path is displayed for the first time, but if my model changes beneath it I need to update this text. Is it possible to cause this method to be called again without reloading the entire section? See code below, and thank you for your help in advance.

```
    -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      ContainerTableViewCell *cell = (ContainerTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      if ([cell.editPhotos count] > 0) {
          return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete %d photos", [cell.editPhotos count]];
      } 
      else{
          return @"Delete Section";
      }
   }
```

---

For a bit of context I have a UICollectionView nested within a UITableViewCell, a notification is sent when a cell is selected. I have tried reloading the section with:

```
 [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

but this is undesirerable because it causes a jump in the tableview and does not display the selection correctly. I have also tried:

```
 [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]];
```

in desperation. While this does cause the correct method to be called it does not change the delete text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem although it is a bit of a hack. The delegate method

```
     -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called once for each cell every time the UITableView enters edit mode. Therefore in order to have the title change when the data changes I toggled the edit mode, using a bool to indicate that I wished to save selected information ie:

```
        cell.retainEditSelection = YES; 
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
        cell.retainEditSelection = NO;
```

I use this every time something is selected that should change my delete text. Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a rudimentary test app where it works as expected.

I think maybe the way you get your data is not the best approach. You are querying a cell that is presumably dequeued and thus might not contain the most up-to-date information.

Instead, you should strive to achieve a true MVC pattern where your data is independent from your views, including collection view cells.

Comment: By works as expected are you receiving multiple calls to titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath? Also, while maybe not the best practice in this case I know querying the cell is not the issue. For any reason if you wanted to change the text of the delete button after that index path had been called upon, how would you do so?